# Popularity of Bayesian methods in statistics and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, references

I know I have seen some research, perhaps in the contexts of time-varying topic models, on the popularity of Bayesian methods in statistics and machine learning over the last 20 years.  Unfortunately I cannot seem to find the citation.  Does anybody know a paper that includes a plot over time of the popularity of Bayesian methods in published statistics and machine learning journals?

Comment: Have a look at https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ba/1340370949